# Using OpenCV inside IOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am trying to use the OpenCV library in my IOS application. I have installed it using `pods` and the current version is 2.4.13. Inside the PrefixHeader.pch file, I have included

```
#ifndef _cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

In my `ViewController.m` file, when I add the line `#import "opencv2/highgui/ios.h"`, I get the build error

```
Parse Issue. Expected ')' ios.h.
```

This ios.h file is included in the library so I have not modified it and its contents:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#import "opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h"

UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image);
void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image,
                     cv::Mat& m, bool alphaExist = false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html#opencvioshelloworld) you need to change the *.m file to *.mm for newer XCode and IOS versions. Try renaming `ViewController.m` to `ViewController.mm` and see if that works.